# jUnit-Testing from another class

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I simplified the problem.

I have 3 classes:

1. My operating class, which has just one static method (add) in it, which should add to ints:

```
    public class T{
        public static int add(int a, int b){
            return a+b;
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure, there is no error in this simple method. Here is my jUnit-Test:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase; 

public class MyJUnitTest extends TestCase{
    T t;
    public boolean test(){
       junit.framework.TestResult t = this.run();
       System.out.println(t.wasSuccessful());
       System.out.println(t.failures.nextElement());
       return t.wasSuccessful();
    }
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       t = new T();
    }
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        t = null;
    }
    //@Test
    public void test1(){
        int[] vgl1 = new int[1];
        int[] vgl2 = new int[1];
        vgl1[0] = t.add(1,2);
        vgl2[0] = 3;
        Assert.assertArrayEquals("Test one", vgl1, vgl2);
    }
}
```

Note: I test with Arrays, because in my not simplified Version of the problem, there are Arrays, which I have to test.

Here comes the problem, I cannot understand: If I run the Test in my IDE I get a success (till here, quite understandable), but if I run a third class with one static method:

```
public class A{
    public static void abc(){
        MyJUnitTest t = new MyJUnitTest();
        t.test();
    }
}
```

I get a failureCount of one and wasSuccessful returns false. Also `System.out.println(t.failures.nextElement());` prints `null(MyJUnitTest): TestCase.fName cannot be null`.

This is, what I cannot understand. The test should be successful!

Also I tried to use jUnit4, which means, I adapted my `MyJUnitTest`-Class. But doing so, I cannot call the run-Method. Is there an equivalent in jUnit4? In my IDE I can just click on "test All", but I need to make the Tests in another class an get the information, wheather all Test were successful.

Comment: honestly, I've never seen any unit test code like this. Also, the fact that you need to instantiate your unit test class to run your tests seems dodgy

Comment: The run-Method is not static. Can you tell me, how to run the tests without instantiating?

Comment: by running it as a unit test.

Comment: Could you provide a code-sample please?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/junit

Comment: I need Class A to run the tests! I could not find any hint, how to do that.

Comment: If you are using Junit it is junit that runs the test.  Of course there is nothing stopping you from implementing your own runner, to do that you should check the docs for the version of junit you are using. Having made the same mistake in the past I would also strongly suggest not having a base test class that you inherit from. It quickly becomes fragile and makes it harder to test.